# y TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: next.js

I am a new programmer and i was following a next js tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zueyEdRZQlk&t=127s. It seems that this code does not work anymore. I have been browsing this website for solutions but they are way too advanced for a beginner like me. Can someone please enlighten me on a way to fix this problem.

`

```
const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
const data = await res.json();

return {
    props: {info: data}
}
```

`

```
`        {info.map(ninja => (
            <div key={ninja.id}>
                <a>
                    <h3>{ninja.name}</h3>
                </a>
            </div>
        ))}
    </div>
);
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we could have a better understanding of what you're asking here ;)

For what I can see, it could be an async issue: is your jsx initialized before you fetch your data ? To be sure your data is well defined before using it, maybe you can try something like :

```
   {Boolean(info) && info.map(ninja => (
        <div key={ninja.id}>
            <a>
                <h3>{ninja.name}</h3>
            </a>
        </div>
    ))}
```